# active model serializers - undefined method 'cached'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to use Active Model Serializers to cache JSONs, using the many guides I saw out there, they all recommend using the built in caching mechanism, in the following manner:

```
class CacheSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  cached
  delegate :cache_key, :to => :object
end
```

and this is my base serializer which all the other cachable serializers should inherit from, however, I always get the following:

```
undefined local variable or method `cached' for CacheSerializer:Class
```

looking at the documentation, I also tried using cache key: 'bla-bla', which provided the same undefined method error.

I have caching enabled and cache store configured out, the caching works in all other parts of the app.

any ideas?

source:
https://robots.thoughtbot.com/fast-json-apis-in-rails-with-key-based-caches-and

Comment: What version of AMS are you using? There have been major changes to the master branch lately which would impact this greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache active model serializers version >= 0.9.0

Since caching is not implemented yet in newer versions of AMS >= (0.9.0) because of rewrite you can use Rails built in caching functionality.

```
def index
  trips = Trip.all
  json = cache ['v1', trips] do
   render_to_string json: trips
  end
  render json: json
end
```

It won’t work in development by default because caching is disabled for development mode.

You can copy config line from your production.rb to development.rb just to test if it’s working:

config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

There is also on [issue](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/851) filed on Github, regarding this.

Comment: this doesn't help, as we want to cache single models and entire result set